# Can I complete a Moderation Analysis with transformed data?

Tags: data-transformation, interaction, spss

I am completing a moderation analysis (model 1) in SPSS with the Hayes PROCESS macro, however I had previously applied a logarithmic transformation to my outcome and moderator variables for them to become normally distributed. Does it make sense to be using standardised variables like these in this analysis given that the output can't be interpreted in a 'real world' sense? If not, what alternatives are there to this? Some guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: This raises many broad and difficult questions. Standardisation has several meanings but it is not often, or not best, used as another word for transformation. If logarithmic transformation is used its most likely benefit is to bring relationships to be more nearly linear, which IIUC is important for what you're doing. Whether logarithms are closer to the real world is another question. Physical scientists are often happy using pH or decibels which are logarithmic scale. Any social scientist thinking about wage or price or GDP increases in percent terms is using logarithmic scale too.

Answer (score 0):

First, how to do things in SPSS is off topic here.

Second, OLS regression does not assume that the variables are normally distributed; it assumes that the errors are normally distributed (and this is only needed for some aspects of regression). But let's assume that the residuals (which we use because errors are unknown) are not normal.

Third, there is no statistical reason you can't include interactions (that is, look at moderation) with transformed variables. Whether this makes sense in your particular context is unclear, since you did not give us context, but, assuming that it does not, then you can use a form of regression that does not make assumptions about the residuals. Robust regression and quantile regression are possible methods.